# why I get error for string array and how to get an specific element from a String array in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-resources

I made an array of questions in res->values->strings

```
<string-array name="Questions">
        <item>Nile River is the longest river in the world.</item>
        <item>Ottawa is the capital of Canada.</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
```

I want to use each element in different places so I tried this syntax:

```
var questionList=resources.getStringArray(R.array.Questions)
..
binding.textViewQuestion.text=questionList[i]
```

I am not very familiar with syntaxes in android and I found this one in developer.android.com; it does not work and I could not find any other way.

There is an error says

```
Resource compilation failed.
```

and when I delete the string array the error will gone. I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: where is your error line? I copy your code and paste in my project, it works.

Comment: did it? I cannot find where is the error coming from. could you guide me?

Comment: You should probably check for errors in strings in your array. Your array syntax is fine and works with normal strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your string array, it could possibly be an syntax error in it.
You can try to just put really simple word in your array and see if the problem is here. Otherwise, the syntax of your other line seems good to me.